# Spring Boot Kotlin entity property val vs var

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I am learning Spring Boot with kotlin and I am so confused with the usage of `var` or `val` for entity property. In some tutorial they use `val` and the other use `var`. So I don't know which is the right one to declare property for entity. At least enlightenment me about this. Please & Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`val` and `var` both are used to declare variables but the main difference between them could be defined as;

> **val**: is used when you declare a variable with a value which you don't want to change or update, it is kind of a constant variable which can only be initialized once. And when you try to change its value, it will show an error like ***Val can not be reassigned***. it is known as immutable variable in kotlin.

On the other hand,

> **var:** is used when you intend to declare a general variable whose value could be changed or updated anywhere in the class. It could be initialized or reassigned multiple times and it is known as mutable variable in kotlin.

I hope this will help you. [There is a good definition with example.](https://medium.com/mindorks/kotlin-series-val-vs-var-difference-android-kotlin-ecad780daeb7)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question - which is directly referring to the use of val and var when creating entity properties (table columns) in spring (which is a slightly different situation than a typical variable declaration)